# How to find number of elements in the set if the numbers are from n1 to n2 spaced by dn?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, programming

If I want to create a space of integers from say $n_1$ to some $n_2$ with step $dn>0$, what is the number of elements of that set?
I am thinking $N=\frac{n2-n1}{dn} + 1$ but this will produce a non-integer number, but i guess the number of elements will be simply the integer part of $N$. Is that correct?

A bigger problem is when the numbers $n_1$ and $n_2$ and $dn$ are no longer integers but real values. The above does not work. E.g. I take in `matlab` (this is just to illustrate since i have not found simpler numbers to show it):

```
n1=126187265.1839116960763931;
n2=157723265.1839116811752319;
dn=300;
a = n1:dn:n2;
```

then the size of a will be 105121 but the formula produces 105120.
What would the formula be like for real numbers?

Comment: Can you confirm that the last element of `a` is `157722965.1839116960763931`, and not the number 300 larger (`157723265.1839116960763931`)?

Answer (score 0):

he problem likely comes down to limited precision. If we do the calculations exactly (using fractions, for example), we find that $1 + \lfloor{\frac{n2 - n1}{dn}}\rfloor$ is in fact 105120 and there are in fact exactly 105120 numbers between `n1` and `n2` with a step of $300$.

I believe Matlab uses 64-bit floating point by default, which means that your `n1` is represented in memory as `0x419E15DC04BC5359`. The first bit is the sign, which is 0 here (meaning positive). The next 11 bits are the exponent of 2, offset by 1023, which is 1049 - 1023 = 26 here. These two parts make up the first three hexadecimal digits (`0x419` here). The rest is the fractional part, or `0xE15DC04BC5359` = $3964684390388569$. We can reconstruct (what the computer thinks) `n1` as $(1 + 3964684390388569 \times 2^{-52}) \times 2^{26}$.

Then, `n1 + 300*105120` is represented `0x41A2CD55025E29AC`, which is exactly the same representation as `n2 = 0x41A2CD55025E29AC`. So Matlab goes ahead and includes it in the range, even though it wouldn't be if we had sufficient precision. `n1 + 300*105120` is actually $157723265.1839116960763931$, which is larger than `n2`.

So what happened? For numbers around `n2`, we have a precision of $2^{-25}$. That is, the next number we can represent after a given number (around the size of `n2`) is $2^{-25}$ larger. The fractional parts of `n1` (and hence `n1 + 105120*300`) and `n2` are slightly more than $2^{-26}$ apart. So to the nearest precision we can get, they're equal.

The same rounding error doesn't happen with your formula due to essentially the same thing. For numbers around `n1`, we have precision of $2^{-26}$, so we *should* be able to distinguish the fractional parts of `n1` and `n2` because they're more than $2^{-26}$ apart.